# Is there any negative impact on Azure App Service Performance, If I implement the monitoring for Azure Web Jobs?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights, azure-app-service-plans

I am working on monitoring the Azure Web Job health with application insights using multi web test by following this [documentation](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/08/11/monitoring-azure-web-jobs-health-with-application-insights/). It is working fine, whenever the web job status is updated then I am getting notification email.
But I have following questions on this:

1. Is there any negative impact in terms of Azure App Service performance?
2. Is the multi web test hits every 5 minutes to Azure App Service?
3. If it hits every time then what about my Azure App Service plan quota, is it exceeded?

So, can anyone suggest me on the above questions?

Comment: it seems you forgot to mention your source / documentation.

Comment: @Kamran, Just now I updated my question with source documentation.

Answer (score 1):

1. No that much. Usually the ping test are less than 100ms.
2. If you set Test freq. to 5 and you have 3 locations then you will have 15 calls every 5 minutes.
3. Yes, it will affect your data out and computation time but these are small numbers. You can ignore it.

**Update:**
@pradeep I collected more information by contacting Azure team.

There is a charge for multi-step web tests (You can create up to 100 availability tests per application resource): https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/application-insights/

But URL ping test are free of cost.

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability or https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/creating-a-web-test-alert-programmatically-with-application-insights/.

Comment: Thanks Kamran, But I need the official documentation for that. if you had please share the documentation.

Comment: Sure, let me see if I can find any.

Comment: Kamran, can you elaborate your answer with more details, in terms of App Service CPU Usage, Latency, Data In/Out, Response Time.

Comment: @pradeep I don't have the exact numbers for you. Data In/Out? this is only the size of your request and the response which is very small (considering gzip option in the headers). CPU usage? You are just reading a log / status even on a free plan this is nothing! Latency/response-time? As you may already tested it this requests are very quick.